# What is the equivalent of Option::take() for a Vec<T>?

Tags: rust

```
struct A {
    pub v: Vec<i32>
}

fn extract(a: &mut A) -> Vec<i32> {
    let res = a.v.clone(); // TODO: move out of a.v
    res
}
```

How to move out a `Vec<T>` while it's inside a `&mut` struct?